# How to scale background image and make it work with browser size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

What I want is that the background image in my div will scale so that it covers the whole browser. If the image is too small, it will increase, if it is to big it will get smaller. I do not want the image to repeat.

[See live demo of my whole web design by clicking here.](http://inmyownview.com/pagan)

Each section in my parallex design is a . They look like this:

```
<section id="start" data-type="background" data-speed="10" style="background: url('http://media.vogue.com/files/2013/01/15/storm-troupers-02_191346273703.jpg') 50% 0 repeat fixed; min-h-margin: 0 auto; height: 1080px;">
    bla bla bla     
</section>
```

Stylesheet

```
section {
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 1920px; 
    height: 1080px;
    position: relative; 
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

There is also a jquery script for the parallex scrolling. In here there is a script for the background position. This may affect something.

```
/**
 * Parallax Scrolling Tutorial
 * For NetTuts+
 *  
 * Author: Mohiuddin Parekh
 *  http://www.mohi.me
 *  @mohiuddinparekh   
 */


$(document).ready(function(){
    // Cache the Window object
    $window = $(window);

   $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
     var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

      $(window).scroll(function() {

        // Scroll the background at var speed
        // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!                              
        var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed')); 

        // Put together our final background position
        var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

        // Move the background
        $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });

}); // window scroll Ends

 });    

}); 
/* 
 * Create HTML5 elements for IE's sake
 */

document.createElement("content");
document.createElement("section");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the CSS [`background-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size) property.

```
section {
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

`min-h-margin` isn't a valid CSS attribute. I'm not sure what you're using that for, or if that's a typo, but I figured it's worth pointing out.

You should also note that `section` may not be being used correctly here. From the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-section-element):

> The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead.

**Edit** from comment below:

> ...but still when then browser is not in full screen you can see the background repeating.

Replace `background-repeat: repeat repeat;` on your `sections` with:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: Alright. These properties are added, but still when then browser is not inn full screen (I use Safari), you can see the background repeating. And on the forth and fifth section the backgrounds are completely messed up @JamesDonnelly

Comment: I've added a bit about `background-repeat` to my answer. :-)

Comment: Maybe consider `background-size: cover;`? "Cover" will scale it up so the background is always completely covered by the image, so won't repeat. Not sure how that will interact with the JavaScript parallax, though.

Comment: Adding `background-repeat: no-repeat;` mess up the JavaScript and the parallex function becomes disabled. `background-size: cover;` makes no difference.

Comment: @VemundEldegard: How are you adding the `no-repeat`? If I add it locally to the CSS then nothing is messed up - but at the same rate I'm unable to replicate the repeating issue you're having.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: I added it first to each `style=""`, but then I tried adding it to the stylesheet. Doing this doesn't mess it up. If you look at the demo, you can see white area where there is no background, and this is the problem.